# How to make a computed prop from two other computed props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My task is to make pagination and search. I solved this problem by creating two computed properties. Separately, they work correctly, but I need to unite them. I can’t figure out how to do this?

```
  paginatedData() {
    const start = this.page * 10;
    const end = start + 10;
    return this.posts.slice(start, end);
  },
  filteredPosts() {
    return this.posts.filter((post) => {
      return post.title.match(this.search);
    });
  },
```

Comment: `paginatedData() {
    const start = this.page * 10;
    const end = start + 10; return filteredPosts().slice(start, end); }`

Comment: Try out `return this.posts.filter((post) => { return post.title.match(search).slice(start, end)  })`

Comment: None of the suggested options work.

Comment: Neither of those functions are valid Vue [filters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)  since they don't accept input parameters. Is it possible that you mean computed data rather than filters?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: @AndreyBelichenko Do you want the `filteredPosts` prop to return only a subset of `paginatedData`?

Comment: @tony19 I just wanted to make one of these two codes so that it worked, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the properties by using the first as the basis for the second. For example, if you want to filter the posts and then paginate

```
paginatedData() {
    const start = this.page * 10;
    const end = start + 10;
    return this.filteredPosts.slice(start, end);
},
filteredPosts() {
    return this.posts.filter((post) => {
      return post.title.match(this.search);
    });
},
```

Or if you want to paginate and then filter

```
paginatedData() {
    const start = this.page * 10;
    const end = start + 10;
    return this.posts.slice(start, end);
},
filteredPosts() {
    return this.paginatedData.filter((post) => {
      return post.title.match(this.search);
    });
},
```

In your template, use whichever computed property is your desired ultimate output (`paginatedData` in the first case, `filteredPosts` in the second).